# ArgumentException: The 'CallbackPath' option must be provided

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I implemented active directory authentication for my Asp.Net core 2 application. Every thing works fine on local but once I deployed the application to server it throws error "ArgumentException: The 'CallbackPath' option must be provided."

I added call back path on my appsettings file: 
tried both:

```
//"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
    "CallbackPath": "/.auth/login/aad/callback"
```

Comment: I don't think the setting is being applied. You have to set it on the OpenID Connect authentication options when configuring authentication.

Comment: you mean in appsettings for appservice on azure portal?

Comment: No, in your code where you configure authentication.

Comment: Can you try adding this line in you startup code after using .AddAuthentication()..AddOpenIdConnect();  And i am assuming you have a openid connect section in your app.settings "OpenIdConnect": {
    "ClientId": "bcd3f4c3-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-e349f2b4bdac",
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/",
    "PostLogoutRedirectUri": "http://localhost:5000",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "ResponseType": "code id_token",
    "Resource": "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
  }

Comment: You can use function like this too in you startup class .AddOpenIdConnect(op=>Configuration.Bind("OpenIdConnect", op));

Comment: i think for  "graph.microsoft.com" we need admin consent.

Answer (score 0):

I added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT as Development in

```
Azure -> App Service(My Appservice) -> Application Settings -> Application Settings
```